# using AWK, how do I convert a decimal number to hexadecimal

Tags: awk

If  I do have an input stream of decimal numbers, e.g.

```
100 2000 599 232
```

and I pass them to awk, how do I print them in Hexadecimal notation?.

for example

```
0x64 0x74D 0x257 0xE8
```

starting script ...

```
echo "100 2000 599 232" | awk '{ print $1 }' #here print in hexa instead of decimal
```

Comment: `echo "100 2000 599 232" | awk '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) printf " 0x%X", $i; print "" }'`??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use printf in awk with a format string to convert to hex:

```
awk '{ printf "%x\n", $1 }'
```

Comment: yeah, this was the answer, awk '{ printf "0x%x\n", $1 }'

Comment: You can use `%#x\n` as the format string to avoid adding the `0x` prefix.

Comment: awesome, it is true

Comment: You might use `%X` if you want uppercase A-F in hex representation as your question suggest, e.g. `awk 'END{printf "%X\n", 255}' emptyfile.txt` output `FF`

Answer (score 0):

quick caveat - mawk 1.3.4 has severe limitations when it comes to printing octal and hex codes :

```
$ gawk  'BEGIN{ printf("%\043.16x\n",8^8*-1-2) }'
0xfffffffffefffffe

$ nawk  'BEGIN{ printf("%\043.16x\n",8^8*-1-2) }'
0xfffffffffefffffe

$ mawk  'BEGIN{ printf("%\043.16x\n",8^8*-1-2) }'
0000000000000000

$ mawk2 'BEGIN{ printf("%\043.16x\n",8^8*-1-2) }'
0xfffffffffefffffe
```

It's not even that large a value (-16777218), and mawk 1.3.4 completely bellyflops. On the flip side, it *can* directly decipher some hex constants (only gawk not in either posix or traditional mode can directly decipher octal constants :

```
$ mawk  'BEGIN { OFMT="%.f"; print +"0xDEADBEEF" }'
3735928559

nawk  'BEGIN { OFMT="%.f"; print +"0xDEADBEEF" }'
3735928559

$ mawk2  'BEGIN { OFMT="%.f"; print +"0xDEADBEEF" }'
0

$ gawk --posix 'BEGIN{ OFMT="%.f"; print +"0xDEADBEEF" }'
3735928559 <====  note the difference - posix mode only can decipher strings
                  the "+" in front is also necessary cuz gawk will just print
                  it as a string otherwise.

$ gawk -e 'BEGIN { OFMT="%.f"; print 0xDEADBEEF }'
3735928559 <==== standard mode only can decipher clear text ones
```

> ```
>  - mawk2 is the only one among those above that 
>    even prints anything out with %p in printf(), 
>    but still erroring out, as such
>
>   mawk2: line 1: invalid control character 'p'
>   in [s]printf format ("0x10f0099da
> ```

> ```
>  - both gawk and nawk properly prints out %a
> ```